# RESTful API design - execute action

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I create application in RESTful standards. I know when I should use GET action, when POST or PUT etc.

But now I have specific case. I don't want to send any data to action ang don't want to receive any data.
I just want to ask server on special addres and action will do some work. Can return just 204 status(NO CONTENT) and that's it. Should I use GET method for this case? Or something different?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely use POST. Most other methods are [meant to be idempotent](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2): they should have same effect on system, no matter how many times you call them with same parameters. Your situation is the opposite: each call initiates execution of *new* task (if I understood you correctly). Also note, that according to the REST paradigm there are no "actions"—only resources. Name your resource "XXX_task" and you will see POST-ing to it as something, that makes sense semantically.